# DataDynamics Active Reports entering extra spaces in long email addresses

Tags: report, reporting, export-to-excel, activereports

I'm using Data Dynamics Active Reports to generate some reports on our website.

Action: User runs a report on user accounts (this contains an email field) and Exports to an excel file.
Issue: If the email is relatively long, extra white space is added in the field.

Has anyone else had this problem? If so, what did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research with DataDynamics and GrapCity I found that this is a known bug they are working on Case 00023478.

To work around it I made the TextBox larger that the email fields were bound to. It's a sucky work around but it's all we have until they fix this issue.

The issue has to do with wrapped text in a texbox that forces line breaks in the excel export.

**EDIT:**

The better, but still sucky, workaround is to make all of your textboxes alignment "Justify". This removes all the spaces from the text on export to excel no matter what size the box, but everything is now justified...

Answer (score 0):

Here, I found a solution to hide blank sub report space:

1. Add group header and footer
2. Check the condition
3. Make Group header or footer visible false/true